# Issue in react native and Paytm integration

Tags: react-native, paytm

I am using react-native-paytm package for the integration when I pass the transaction credentials and the checksum to the sdk I get some error .

Response from the Paytm :

```
{"status":"Success","RESPMSG":"Your payment has been declined by your bank. Please contact your bank for any queries. If money has been deducted from your account, your bank will inform us within 48 hrs and we will refund the same","CURRENCY":"INR","BANKTXNID":"","RESPCODE":"501","MID":"JyiXFm81685157765627","TXNAMOUNT":"100.00","ORDERID":"ORDER00001","CHECKSUMHASH":"2DsqlZ1jlK+HlcdbCj1E6ELce21saT12wVtETRLkHj2rkh6cg6xndopTKPfzi/VFjoU8iMv64kCm/IjAk3a87jd43+/TXuEVIYN0LrYxzqo=","STATUS":"TXN_FAILURE"}
```

Answer (score 1):

I solved this issue by raising this to the Paytm support team .

Comment: Can you share what was the response from the paytm support team, we are stuck in the same bug.

Comment: sorry for late reply. You just have to raise an issue stating the problem they will solve it from their end .

Comment: Ok, Thanks for the reply. Will communicate with Paytm technical support.

Comment: In my case, Paytm gateway account is not yet activated, due to KYC document